# Help with code for this table?

Tags: tables

I have tried writing different code for the following table (attached) but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Here is a code I used but when I tried to generate it in LaTeX, it did not work. The text is too large inside the cells. I am fairly new to LaTeX, so any help would be great.

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{8cm}||p{8m}}
 \hline
Person A  &  Person B \\
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Key Generation} \\
\hline
Choose two primes p and q.
Choose encryption exponent  e with gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1.
Share private key n = pxq and e.  & \\
 \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Encryption} \\
&  Choose plaintext P.
Use person A’s key (n, e) to compute  C \equiv P^e (mod n).
Send ciphertext  C to Person A.\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Decryption} \\
Find d such that 
ed \equiv 1 (mod \phi(n)) .
Compute for P \equiv  C^d (mod n). & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Make sure you enclose all math declarations in math mode. For example gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1 should be $gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$

Comment: Since you say it compiles: is the whole tabular enclosed in math mode somehow? Also, column A is 8cm and column B 8m?

Answer (score 7):

I'd remove most of the rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr 0.5\columnwidth-\tabcolsep}
  >{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr 0.5\columnwidth-\tabcolsep}
  @{}
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Person A}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Person B} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Key Generation} \tabularnewline

Choose two primes $p$ and $q$.

Choose encryption exponent  $e$ with $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$.

Share private key $n = p\cdot q$ and $e$. \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Encryption} \tabularnewline
&
Choose plaintext $P$.

Use person $A$'s key $(n, e)$ to compute  $C \equiv P^e \pmod{n}$.

Send ciphertext  $C$ to Person $A$. \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\itshape Decryption} \tabularnewline
Find $d$ such that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$.

Compute for $P\equiv C^d\pmod{n}$. \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Description of RSA}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

A solution that combines ideas of Mico's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362557/16967), egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362592/16967), and of my own. I do not think, that the subtitles belong to both persons but to the following action description. By moving the subtitles to the actions, the many
distracting lines could be reduced significantly.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
  \toprule
    Person A  &  Person B \\
  \midrule
    \emph{Key Generation}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Choose two primes $p$ and $q$.

    Choose encryption exponent  $e$ with $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$.

    Share private key $n = p\cdot q$ and $e$.  & \\
    &\emph{Encryption}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    &  Choose plaintext $P$.

    Use person $A$'s key $(n, e)$ to compute  $C \equiv P^e \pmod{n})$.

    Send ciphertext  $C$ to Person $A$.\\
    \emph{Decryption}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Find $d$ such that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ .

    Compute for $P\equiv C^d\pmod{n}$. & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

This solution also allows to save some vertical space by moving the second and third action to the top by the height of a table row. It reduces the large white "holes" in the table and makes it easier for TeX to find page breaks. But the line separating the subtitle should not move in the area of the previous action.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\edef\TabularRowHeight{\the\dimexpr-\arraystretch\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YY}
  \toprule
    Person A  &  Person B \\
  \midrule
    \emph{Key Generation}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Choose two primes $p$ and $q$.

    Choose encryption exponent  $e$ with $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$.

    Share private key $n = p\cdot q$ and $e$.  & \\[\TabularRowHeight]
    &\emph{Encryption}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
    &  Choose plaintext $P$.

    Use person $A$'s key $(n, e)$ to compute  $C \equiv P^e \pmod{n})$.

    Send ciphertext  $C$ to Person $A$.\\[\TabularRowHeight]
    \emph{Decryption}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){1-1}
    Find $d$ such that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ .

    Compute for $P\equiv C^d\pmod{n}$. & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with less vertical space]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that uses a `tabularx` environment, with width set to `\textwdith`, and ragged-right mode for each of the two columns. I've also set `\extrarowheight` to a small positive length, to give a more "open" look to the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Y|Y|}
 \hline
Person A  &  Person B \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Key Generation} \\
\hline
Choose two primes $p$ and $q$.

Choose encryption exponent  $e$ with $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$.

Share private key $n = p\cdot q$ and $e$.  & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Encryption} \\
\hline
&  Choose plaintext $P$.

Use person $A$'s key $(n, e)$ to compute  $C \equiv P^e \pmod{n})$.

Send ciphertext  $C$ to Person $A$.\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Decryption} \\
\hline
Find $d$ such that $ed \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(n)}$ .

Compute for $P\equiv C^d\pmod{n}$. & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I vote positive your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your problem, really. Seems you just have a bunch of typo's and mistakes. I get

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}
\toprule
Person A  &  Person B \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Key Generation} \\
\midrule
Choose two primes $p$ and $q$.
Choose encryption exponent  $e$ with $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) =  1$.
Share private key $n = p\times q$ and $e$.  & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Encryption} \\
\midrule
&  Choose plaintext $P$.
Use person A's key $(n, e)$ to compute  $C \equiv P^e (\text{mod} n)$.
Send ciphertext  $C$ to Person A.\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Decryption} \\
\midrule
Find $d$ such that 
$ed \equiv 1 (\text{mod} \phi(n))$ .
Compute for $P \equiv  C^d (\text{mod} n)$. & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Hope I didn't make too many mistakes myself. I made the columns a bit narrower. 6 cm looks right to me.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but the Person A and Person B headers are not centered. It is easy to fix using multicolumn here too (with only one column) :-)

Comment: You shouldn't use vertical rules with `booktabs`: there are gaps in these rules – unless you  remove the horizontal rules padding.

Comment: @FabianPijcke What would be the code to center Person A and Person B?

Comment: @Bernard I tried adding a caption such as \caption{RSA encryption} and it says error. It messes my code up. What can I do?

Comment: @Lennay Truna: That's normal: the code does not use the `table` environment. So, either you let the `tabular` float,  nesting it in `table`, or you use  `\captionof{table}{RSA encryption}` (requires the `caption`or `capt-of` package).

Comment: @LennayTruna, egreg's answer features centering these headers :-)